# How Interface reference access class method and variable in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am not sure how `expr` which is a reference of an Interface can call the variable declared in Num class variable. I am learning it through kotlin Koans. Can someone explain?

```
  fun eval(expr: Expr): Int =
    when (expr) {
        is Num ->  expr.value
        is Sum -> eval(expr.left)+eval(expr.right)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown expression")
    }

interface Expr
class Num(val value: Int) : Expr

class Sum(val left: Expr, val right: Expr) : Exp
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, when you declare a class like this:

```java
class Num(val value: Int) : Expr
```

it means that class `Num` *implements* interface `Expr`. It means that any instance of `Num` can be used as an instance of `Expr`, so function `eval` can receive an instance of `Num` as a parameter.

In `when` operator you check what is the actual implementation of `Expr` that was used to create instance `expr`. Branch `is Num ->` is called when the actual type of `expr` is `Num`, so Kotlin automatically recognizes that in this branch `expr` is an instance of `Num`, so you can use properties of `Num` class. This Kotlin feature is called [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

Answer (score 4):

At the beginning, you can improve you code. If you use `Sealed` class.

```
Sealed class Expr {
   class Num(val value: Int) : Expr()
   class Sum(val left: Expr, val right: Expr): Expr()
} 
fun eval(expr: Expr): Int =
    when (expr) {
        is Num ->  expr.value
        is Sum -> eval(expr.left) + eval(expr.right)
    }
```

After it you don't need to use else block with some unknown exception.

About your question. `expr` has access to val value, because it's `Num` object, not `Expr`. In your example on start you check object in when block, if expr is Num, then you can take var from Num class, if fields of this class are not private.
When you call method `eval()` you can pass Num or Sum object, if you can pass `Num`, you can get `value` in when block, if you pass a var with type `Sum`, you can get `left` and `right` value.